# Identify top most iframe from top window after postmessage call

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I have a piece of JavaScript that run from within an iFrame. This iFrame could be a direct child of the main (top) window or it could be a child at any level (2nd, 3rd, 4th, nth) within nested iFrames. 
Within the JavaScript a call is made to the top window using postmessage. I should add that the top window, the iFrames and the JavaScript could potentially all have different domains. So far I have this part working successfully using `window.top.postMessage(message, "*");` where `message` contains the string I'm passing through.
What I need to do it identify the iFrame the sits directly on the top window (the first iFrame) from within the callback function of the postmessage event listener. I need to be able to do this so I can remove it (and it's container div) from the top window.
I'm not sure if this is even possible but any pointers in any direction would be helpful.

Comment: the top's message event object has a link back to the sending window as a property, i can't recall, maybe e.target?

Comment: Thanks @dandavis however e.target references the top window rather than the first iFrame which is what I'm after.

Comment: yeah, well some other event property point to the sending window, dig around in the dev tools.